# Check if property exists Groovy

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I am using multi-branch plugin in Jenkins and polling my git repo to see if there are any changes. My problem is that when it polls, my $GIT_BRANCH_NAME variable doesn't exist and the build fails.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: GIT_BRANCH_NAME for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
```

I tried checking for

```
if (!bindings.hasProperty(GIT_BRANCH_NAME)){
echo "Why is this not working"
env.GIT_BRANCH_NAME = sh(script: "git rev-parse HEAD", returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

and

```
 if (!project.hasProperty(GIT_BRANCH_NAME)){
    echo "Why is this not working"
    env.GIT_BRANCH_NAME = sh(script: "git rev-parse HEAD", returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
```

It doesn't work though. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't it be `hasProperty("GIT_BRANCH_NAME")` ?

Comment: That gives an error-> `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: project for class: groovy.lang.Binding
 at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
if (!bindings.properties."${GIT_BRANCH_NAME}")){
    echo "Why is this not working"
    env.GIT_BRANCH_NAME = sh(script: "git rev-parse HEAD", returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

UPD:

As far as I understood the problem is that your class doesn't have neither `bindings`, nor `project` and `GIT_BRANCH_NAME` variables declared (or they're not passed into the binding from outside). Is it possible to publish the entire class and probably the script executor(binding or like that)?

Comment: That gives an error - > 
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: bindings for class: groovy.lang.Binding
 at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)`

Comment: Does that mean that you're trying to get a missing property from a missing property?

Comment: Haha yes. I did get around it by disabling the auto update for now.

Comment: its probably `binding` without the plural 's'. the current answer has a double closing round brace and thus will not run at all as it is.

Answer (score 1):

some things to know (or at least to guess) upfront:

- Jenkins Groovy runtime uses the `env` object(?) for managing current environment variables - this means its not guaranteed that any `env` member will also be present within the "binding" system
- certain members, such as WORKSPACE might only be there when running in a node/agent/ws covered context.
- some/all(?) members are same time present as `env.<name>` and `<name>`
- trying to access a non-existing member for `env.<name>` will result in null whilst for the same case accessing `<name>` will raise a fault.
- there are special members that will fail locating them via binding or similar class systems.

thus i would recommend to realize code that looks something like that:

```
if (env.WORKSPACE != null) {
    println "WORKSPACE=${WORKSPACE}"  // or ${env.WORKSPACE}
    // checking for an empty string value is now a simple story.
} else {
    println "WORKSPACE is null"
}
```